# Pipe With Floats

Tags: c, pipe

The pipe keeps truncating the whole part of the number except for the first one

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void errexit(char *errMsg)
{
    printf("\n About to exit: %s", errMsg) ;
    fflush(stdout) ;
    exit(1) ;
}

int main()
{
    int ret ;
    pid_t pid ;
    double adder ;
    double value ;
    char fifoName[] = "/tmp/testfifo" ;
    char errMsg[1000] ;
    FILE *cfp ;
    FILE *pfp ;

    ret = mknod(fifoName, S_IFIFO | 0600, 0) ;      // 0600 gives read, write permissions to user and none to group and world

    if(ret < 0)
    {
        sprintf(errMsg,"Unable to create fifo: %s",fifoName) ;
        errexit(errMsg) ;
    } 

    pid = fork() ;

    if(pid == 0)
    {
        // child -- open the named pipe and write an integer to it 
        cfp = fopen(fifoName,"w") ;
        if(cfp == NULL) 
            errexit("Unable to open fifo for writing") ;
        adder = 1.1 ;
        value = 1.1 ;
        while (value < 10)
        {
            ret=fprintf(cfp,"%lf",value) ;
            printf("Child sending %lf\n", value) ;
            //fflush(cfp) ;
            value = value + adder ;
        }
        exit(0) ;
    } 
    else
    {
        printf("Spawned child %d\n", pid) ;

        // parent - open the named pipe and read an integer from it
        pfp = fopen(fifoName,"r") ;
        if(pfp == NULL) 
            errexit("Unable to open fifo for reading") ;

        //while (fscanf(pfp, "%e", &value) > 0)
        while (fscanf(pfp, "%lf", &value) > 0)
        {
            printf("This is the parent. Received value %lf from child on fifo \n", value) ;

            sleep(1) ;
            value = 0 ;
        }
        fclose(pfp) ;
        printf("Bye\n") ;
        unlink(fifoName); // Delete the created fifo
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Output

```
Spawned child 17767
Child sending 1.100000
Child sending 2.200000
Child sending 3.300000
Child sending 4.400000
Child sending 5.500000
This is the parent. Received value 1.100000 from child on fifo 
Child sending 6.600000
Child sending 7.700000
Child sending 8.800000
Child sending 9.900000
This is the parent. Received value 0.200000 from child on fifo 
This is the parent. Received value 0.300000 from child on fifo 
This is the parent. Received value 0.400000 from child on fifo 
This is the parent. Received value 0.500001 from child on fifo 
This is the parent. Received value 0.600001 from child on fifo 
This is the parent. Received value 0.700001 from child on fifo 
This is the parent. Received value 0.800001 from child on fifo 
This is the parent. Received value 0.900000 from child on fifo
```

It gets the first one right 1.1, but after that it looses the whole part but gets the decimal part right.  GCC compiler on Fedora 25.  I've been able to get strings and integers through the pipe, but not having much luck with getting a double to go through the pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the producer is writing values like this:

```
fprintf(cfp,"%lf",value) ;
```

with no spaces, then the values will appear as one continuous stream:

> 1.1000002.2000003.3000004.400000...

I'm guessing the consumer is reading, e.g., `1.1000002` then stopping (because the next `.` isn't part of the value), leaving, e.g., `.2000003` for the next fscanf.

If you add a newline or space to separate the values, then things should work.

Comment: Thanks, been stuck for several hours.  Changed the one line to

Comment: Thanks, been stuck for several hours. Changed the one line to 
 ret=fprintf(cfp,"%lf ",value) ;
working good now

Comment: @brianl> though completely optional, a common convention when using text-based messages in a stream is to use either '\n' (most common case) or '\0' (when text may include linefeed) as a delimiter.